# eCommerce system for configurable products

Tags: looking-for-a-script, ecommerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

I'm looking for a eCommerce solution for configurable products.

I know I could achieve this in Magento but this isn't an option at the moment as we currently have a hosting contract that we can't install it on and changing hosts isn't an option currently.

I'm looking for the following functionality:

Selection 1

- A
- B
- C

Selection 2

- D
- E
- F
- G
- H
- I

If a user selects an option in selection 1 the only some of the options in selection 2 will be available so if they chose A in S1 then maybe only options D,E, and F would be available; but if they chose B in S1 then options D,F,G and I would be available and so on...

Once all sections are chosen it needs to output the relevant price/product SKU for that configured product.

My main experience of ecommerce is via Magento so I'm not sure if this is standard functionality in other ecommerce solutions or something out of the ordinary as i was using the Simple Configurable Products script on Magento previously.

I should also add that we are also using a wordpress set up alongside so if there is a module or solution that integrates with wordpress that would be great, not a major issue if it is a standalone solution though as I can modify templates to make a seamless experience for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CS-Cart has a pretty nice product configurator. Go here http://demo.cs-cart.com/professional/ and click on Build your PC in the top right. This graphic will take you to a configurable product to build a computer

Magento's Demo looks like it should do what you want isn't this possible with your current setup? http://demo.magentocommerce.com/my-computer.html

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, do you know if there is an open source alternative?

Comment: I don't think their community edition has that feature just the pro edition. They just came out with 3.0rc which looks great. I would pay the $300 for pro edition if a few sales would make that up it's worth it. Plus the easy to use datafeed builder so you can have Google, Bing, TheFind and others automatically getting product datafeeds from your site.

Comment: I updated my answer to include magentos demo, isn't that close to what you want?

Comment: "I know I could achieve this in Magento but this isn't an option at the moment as we currently have a hosting contract that we can't install it on and changing hosts isn't an option currently." :(

Comment: I read that part of your post I just wasn't sure why you couldn't install it or use it with Magento. You're locked into a hosting contract. Is magento installed from source or some hosted provider? Did you sign a contract with a pen and mail it to a company? Otherwise I would say you're not legally bound to any contract and I would contact someone at your hosting company explain your position and say you want to cancel your account. If they don't let you call your credit card company to cancel the recurring billing. Not suggesting a chargeback but simply cancel if the host doesn't let you out.